# How to disable network in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, network-programming

I have an application which is using both Restkit for posting and getting objects and MKMapView for viewing a map. Is there any general property to switch off network access (both wifi and cellular) in an app?

I want a method that look something like this:

```
[Reachabillity disableNetwork]
```

And when I try to access network (posting objects or loading new maps to MKMapView) I get a network error.

Is it possible or should I take care of it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to disable the network on the entire phone, forget about it, unless you're making a jailbreak-application.

With that said, jailbroken applications can do as they like, so to disable the WiFi of the phone, you can do this:

```
Class _SBWifiManager = objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager"); // Steal a WiFi class from SpringBoard
[[_SBWifiManager sharedInstance] setWiFiEnabled:NO]; // disable
```

And you can probably achieve something similar if you try to.

If you're not interested in that solution, you'd be better off taking care of it manually, as you mentioned.

Comment: I only want to disable it in the app, not the entire phone.